# Is there a limit to how many items you can list horizontally in html?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a list of items that I'm displaying horizontally on a page using flexbox, once the list goes beyond what can be displayed on the screen the scrollbar kicks in but items in the front disappear. Is this a documented limit to the number of items or am I doing something funky?

Here's a code pen to show what I'm talking about: https://codepen.io/johnniesmee/pen/OJgvopb

```css
.listNav {
  margin-top: 15px;
  max-width: 100vw;
  overflow: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.listBand {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.listItem {
  min-width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="listNav">
  <div class="listBand" id="band">
    <div class="listItem">1</div>
    <div class="listItem">2</div>
    <div class="listItem">3</div>
    <div class="listItem">4</div>
    <div class="listItem">5</div>
    <div class="listItem">6</div>
    <div class="listItem">7</div>
    <div class="listItem">8</div>
    <div class="listItem">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are the expected results?

Comment: Once there are enough items to force the scrollbar (29 items in my case), items from the front get truncated.  So if I set the # of items to 40, the scrollbar appears but the first item is 8.

"inline-flex" and 'space-between' both seem to work; but it be great if someone could explain why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try '**display: inline-flex;**'

```
.listBand {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

[image: inline-flex]

Answer (score -1):

Can you put  ( justify-content:space-between;)

Answer (score -1):

Try **'justify-content: space-between;'**

```
    .listBand {
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
    }
```

Comment: I can't accept multiple answers as the solution, and I'm too new to cast an up vote; but I wanted to let you know that your solution worked also